# How do I ensure that users enter a correct format for date?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to force users to enter date in this format "18/7/2019". I want an error message to display "wrong format" if user enters date in format other than this one. How do I do it?

```
On Error GoTo Update_Exit:
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim qdf As QueryDef
     Dim sql As String

     Set db = CurrentDb()
     Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("SearchEffectiveDate")


     sqlString = "SELECT KissFlowtbl.* FROM KissFlowtbl WHERE Effective_Date Like  '*" & Me.txtEffectiveDate & "*'  "
     qdf.sql = sqlString

      If Nz(Me.txtEffectiveDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Effective Date"
        Resume Exit_Update
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong Format"
        Resume Exit_Update
      End If

DoCmd.OpenQuery "SearchEffectiveDate"

      qdf.Close
      CurrentDb.Close

Exit_Update:
Exit Sub

Update_Exit:
If Err.Number = 2501 Then
    Resume Exit_Update
Else
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Update
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy, indeed not for this format. You can see how to manage when using the ISO format:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

If you have no account, browse for the link: Read the full article.

Code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.DateEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry)